# how to toggle a className between two list items in react

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, validation, html-lists

I have an un-order list. If `li` 1 clicked, `className="selected"` will be assigned to it. If `li` 2 is clicked, `className="selected"` will be assigned to it, and `className="selected"` will be removed from `li` 1. How do I do this? Thanks for your help in advance.

```
 <ul>
      <li role="option" aria-selected="false">
        yes
      </li>
      <li role="option" aria-selected="false">
        no
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a state variable for keeping the current selected item. Then check each li against the state variable.

```
 const selectionArray = ['yes', 'no'];
  const [selectedITem, setSelectedItem] = useState('yes');
  return (
    <ul>
      {selectionArray.map((item) => {
        return (
          <li
            onClick={() => {
              setSelectedItem(item);
            }}
            className={selectedITem === item ? 'selected' : ''}
            key={'selection-' + item}
            role="option"
            aria-selected="false"
          >
            {item}
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to Call function on OnClick of li and add value in li, then you will get value of li. See below:

```
const [selectedMenu, setSelectedMenu] = useState([]);

  function onClickMenu(e) {
   console.log("val:", e.target.value)
   setSelectedMenu(e.target.value)
  }

   <ul>
    <li role="option" value="1" aria-selected="false" onClick={(e) => onClickMenu(e)} 
    className={selectedMenu === 1 ? 'selected' : ''}>
      yes
    </li>
    <li role="option" value="2" onClick={(e) => onClickMenu(e)}  aria-selected="false" className={selectedMenu === 2 ? 'selected' : ''}>
      no
    </li>
  </ul>
```